# Twitter username not displaying tweets JSON

Tags: javascript, xml, json, rest, twitter

I am trying to get the tweets associated with this user @WeAreShootProd but the JSON and XML is empty.

https://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.xml?screen_name=WeAreShootProd

https://search.twitter.com/search.json?rpp=10&callback=?&q=from:WeAreShootProd

As you can see from this link there are at least 5 tweets

https://twitter.com/WeAreShootProd

Does anyone know why they aren't appearing in the XML or JSON?

Thanks very much

Comment: This is working but the JSON call isn't working - http://shootproduction01.uwpistol.net/js/test.html anyone know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I tried the URL you provided, I see the following response:

```
{
  errors: [
    {
      message: "The Twitter REST API v1 is no longer active. Please migrate to API v1.1. https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/overview.",
      code: 68
    }
  ]
}
```

I suspect the problem was that in the JSON call, you had two question marks in the query portion of the URI. But whatever the problem was at the time, the issue is rather moot. That version of the Twitter API is no longer supported.